# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AllPosts'

Tags: string, flutter

I'm not sure why it can't saveform. Please help me QAQ this is messing up my life

This is the error:
lib/navpages/upload/edit_post_screen.dart:98:65: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AllPosts'.

- 'AllPosts' is from 'package:pinsta/providers/all_posts.dart' ('lib/providers/all_posts.dart').
  onPressed:() => saveForm(i,caption!),
  ^

  ```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:pinsta/models/post.dart';
   import 'package:pinsta/providers/all_posts.dart';
   import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


   class EditPostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
     static String routeName = '/edit-post';

     @override
     State<EditPostScreen> createState() => _EditPostScreenState();
   }

   class _EditPostScreenState extends State<EditPostScreen> {
     var form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

     String? caption?? ;



     void saveForm(int i, AllPosts myPosts) {
       bool isValid = form.currentState!.validate();
       if (isValid) {
         form.currentState!.save();
         print(caption);

         myPosts.updatePost(i,caption);

         FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
         form.currentState!.reset();
         caption = null;

         ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
           SnackBar(
             content: Row(
               children: [
                 Flexible(child: Text('updated', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.5))),
               ],
             ),
             duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
           ),
         );

       }
     }


     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       AllPosts postList1 = Provider.of <AllPosts> (context);
       int i = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as int;

       return Scaffold(
         resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
         body: SafeArea(
           child: Padding(
             padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0,vertical: 18.0),
             child: Column(
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
               children: [
                 Image.asset('assets/images/upload_image.png',height: 200,
                   width: 200,),
                 SizedBox(height: 50.0,),
                 Form(
                   key: form,
                   child: Column(
                     children: [
                       SizedBox(
                         height: 60.0,
                       ),
                       TextFormField(
                         decoration: InputDecoration(
                             prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.people, color: Colors.grey),
                             hintText: 'caption',
                             border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)
                             )
                         ),
                         validator: (value) {
                           if (value == null)
                             return caption;
                         },
                         onSaved: (value) {caption = value;},
                       ),
                       SizedBox(
                         height: 50.0,
                       ),
                       Padding(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                         child: Container(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               color: Colors.redAccent,
                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                             ),
                             child: Center(
                               child: TextButton(
                                 onPressed:() => saveForm(i,caption!),
                                 child: Text(
                                   'Update', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                                 ),
                               ),
                             )
                         ),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
  ```

This is the provider:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import '../models/post.dart';
    
    class AllPosts with ChangeNotifier {
      List <Post> myPosts = [];
    
      List<Post> getMyPosts() {
        return myPosts;
      }
    
      void addPost(imageUrl, caption, username) {
        myPosts.insert(0, Post(imageUrl: imageUrl, caption: caption, username:username));
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      void removePost(i) {
        myPosts.removeAt(i);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      void updatePost(i,caption ) {
        myPosts[i].caption = caption;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You method `void saveForm(int i, AllPosts myPosts)` has `AllPosts` as the 2nd parameter but you are calling it with `saveForm(i,caption!),` passing a String (caption) as argument.

Comment: what should i do tho?

Comment: So. the easy part is change  your `void saveForm(int i, AllPosts myPosts)` to `void saveForm(int i, String caption)`.

Now you need an instance of AllPosts in this widget to interact with your Posts and replace `myPosts`.  If you just create a new Instance of AllPosts it would be empty, so it wouldn't work. 

So the "AllPosts" would either to persist the Posts, so you could get and update it in a new instance, or pass down the instance of "AllPosts" that you created in your "home" to other widgets access it. Sending it as a parameter to other widgets would be the "simplest" way